# Javascript - Mixed list of Integers and Strings

Tags: javascript, list, loops

So I'm trying to create a script that has a hardcoded list of lets say 10 entries of strings and 10 entries of integers.

I then want to assign two variables. numberOfIntegers & numberOfCharacters.
For each Int in the list I add a 1 to the variable numberOfIntegers.
For each String in the list I add 1 per each character to the variable numberOfCharacters.

I have tried solving this with a foreach and typeof but cant seem to get it to work and I now turn to other brains in hope that someone has an idea on how to solve this.

Here is the code

```
var numberOfIntegers = 0;
var numberOfCharacters = 0;


var list = ["tdgatzsdsbec",2, "wjlkqbgusdfc",21,"pmyxfmcwbzeg",0213,"tmhnfrkokodr",
            92015325,"wowkvodnizlm",312893251,"mylpfjvlepal",8585,"mvetmwqtqxrw",2145232,"nhamifvtpblz", 888,
            "uvcfspifmipk", 12337,"dcjupeufpknt"];



for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
      if (typeof list.indexOf(i) === Number){
          numberOfIntegers++;
      }
      if (typeof list.indexOf(i) === String){
          i.length += numberOfCharacters;
      }
}

console.log(numberOfIntegers);
console.log(numberOfCharacters);
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Added it in the new edit

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
    var numberOfIntegers = 0;
var numberOfCharacters = 0;


var list = ["tdgatzsdsbec",2, "wjlkqbgusdfc",21,"pmyxfmcwbzeg",0213,"tmhnfrkokodr",
            92015325,"wowkvodnizlm",312893251,"mylpfjvlepal",8585,"mvetmwqtqxrw",2145232,"nhamifvtpblz", 888,
            "uvcfspifmipk", 12337,"dcjupeufpknt"];



for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

      if (typeof list[i] === 'number'){
          numberOfIntegers++;
      }
      if (typeof list[i] === 'string'){
          numberOfCharacters+=list[i].length ;
      }
}

console.log(numberOfIntegers);
console.log(numberOfCharacters);
```

DEmo:

```js
var numberOfIntegers = 0;
var numberOfCharacters = 0;


var list = ["tdgatzsdsbec",2, "wjlkqbgusdfc",21,"pmyxfmcwbzeg",0213,"tmhnfrkokodr",
            92015325,"wowkvodnizlm",312893251,"mylpfjvlepal",8585,"mvetmwqtqxrw",2145232,"nhamifvtpblz", 888,
            "uvcfspifmipk", 12337,"dcjupeufpknt"];



for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

      if (typeof list[i] === 'number'){
          numberOfIntegers++;
      }
      if (typeof list[i] === 'string'){
          numberOfCharacters+=list[i].length ;
      }
}

console.log(numberOfIntegers);
console.log(numberOfCharacters);
```

First, you should use list[i], to get desired value from array, then, check what `type_of` is returning. You have used strict equation, but you got strings 'number', and 'string' as result...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object with the wanted types as properties and iterate the data and take the type as acessor for the object to increment the value.

```js
var list = ["tdgatzsdsbec", 2, "wjlkqbgusdfc", 21, "pmyxfmcwbzeg", 213, "tmhnfrkokodr", 92015325, "wowkvodnizlm", 312893251, "mylpfjvlepal", 8585, "mvetmwqtqxrw", 2145232, "nhamifvtpblz", 888, "uvcfspifmipk", 12337, "dcjupeufpknt"],
    result = { number: 0, string: 0 };

list.forEach(v => result[typeof v]++);

console.log(result);
```